# How can I run compiz-fusion effects with ATI Radeon x1250?

Tags: 10.10, compiz, ati

I was installing ubuntu 10.10 to my friend laptop, but when trying to set up effects, I got an error. Then I tried to install proprietary drivers, but this card is too old and no longer supported. :( Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be REALLY hack-ish, but you could install the old driver from here:
http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-8.42.3-x86.x86_64.run
and follow the guide here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=588605
....might be more pain than it's worth though, and it will effectively move you into the "unsupported" bracket.

Yes, I know that how-to is OLD(3 years), but it gets the old driver installed-ish and working sort of.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same video card in my laptop and find that I don't need to install any drivers. The open-source radeon drivers have improved recently and seem to work ok at least for Compiz (no good for games though). Unfortunately, there is some problem that just appeared in Unity-3D and compiz with Ubuntu 11.10, but 11.04 works great.